# How to get number of visible lines in JTextArea with line wrap enabled?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am wondering how it is possible to get the number of visible lines in `JTextArea` when line wrap  is set to true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which lines are visible in scrollable JTextArea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165617/how-to-determine-which-lines-are-visible-in-scrollable-jtextarea)

Comment: Are you trying to determine the preferred size of a text area with (text and) line wrap?  Given your comment on the only 'answer', that's as best I can figure out what you actually need.

Comment: I add the text to jtextarea, it gets wrapped, I need to know how many lines are visible. Not the content that is visible, and not viewport divided by font metrics - as it doesn't help with the wrapped lines.

Comment: Ok I think I can see the solution - I extract the text as in the answer linked and then parse for line separators (or against the source text) to determine the number of lines... might work actually...

Comment: There are now "line separators" when the text is wrapped...

Comment: If the text area has had [`setRows(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setRows-int-) called, either explicitly or by the constructor, and is in a layout/constraint that honors the height, the 'number of visible rows' will be exactly [`getRows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#getRows--).  Perhaps it would be better if you describe what the point of this is.  What are you going to **do with the value of '# lines displayed'?**

Comment: Thanks MP, Andrew, I am not calling setRows and in my test getRows() says 0 even with a resize event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your definition of "visible lines"? For example what if:

1. half of a line is displayed. Does it count as a line or not?
2. half of a wrapped line is displayed. Does it count as a line or not?

Anyway, I think the way to approach is to use the location of the viewport and the `viewToModel()` method to get the offsets off the text on the first and last line displayed in the viewport.

Then you can use the `Element` structure of the document to determine the line number of these offsets. Once you know the line numbers you calculate the difference between the line numbers.

Finally depending on your answers to my questions above, you adjust the line number as required.

Here is the basics to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestTextArea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextArea();
    }

    public TestTextArea() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestTextAreaPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestTextAreaPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea textArea;

        public TestTextAreaPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            textArea = new JTextArea(20, 100);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);

            try
            {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader( "TestTextArea.java" );
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                textArea.read( br, null );
                br.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e2) { System.out.println(e2); }

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            add(scrollPane);
            scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    if (textArea.getText().length() > 0) {
                        JViewport viewport = (JViewport) e.getSource();
                        Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();

                        Point p = viewRect.getLocation();
                        int startIndex = textArea.viewToModel(p);

                        int lineHeight = textArea.getFontMetrics( textArea.getFont() ).getHeight();
                        p.y += viewRect.height - lineHeight;
                        int endIndex = textArea.viewToModel(p);

                        Element root = textArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
                        int startLine =  root.getElementIndex( startIndex );
                        int endLine =  root.getElementIndex( endIndex );
                        int lines = endLine - startLine + 1;
                        System.out.println(lines);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will run more test but for now it works great! Cheers!